# Validate Boo script syntactically without running it

Tags: syntax, boo

I have use BOO as an embedded script language in my own program. And I want to check the syntax errors of a  script which a user writes. So I don't need to run the script by something like interpreter.Eval method and I need just running the first steps of compiler in order to discover the syntax error in user's script. Is there any way I can do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://boo.codehaus.org/How+To+Compile:

> There are basically three ways to compile your boo code:

- through the booc utility;
- through the booc task (one of the nant tasks);
- through the Boo.Lang.Compiler API;